# MIB conversion to .py using mibdump.py -- missing source MIBs

Tags: python, snmp, mib

I want to use SNMP-Lab's snmpsim-Tool to simulate a non-public MIB (lets call it myMIB, because I don't know if I'm allowed to mention the official name) for SNMP queries.

I do have the MIB in .mib format, when I try to use this existing file for simulation via mib2dev.py as described in the official documentation it gives the following error: "myMIB.py[co] not found... []" in all search paths.

This might make sense, given my file is not in .py but rather in .mib format.

Therefore I tried to convert the .mib to .py first, using mibdump.py --mib-source=file:///usr/share/snmp/... myMIB.

This gives the following error: Missing source MIBs: SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC. Hence the conversion fails.

My .mib states in definitions: IMPORTS [...] MODULE-IDENTITY FROM SNMPv2-SMI;

So it is defined in my .mib, but i cannot seem to include SNMPv2-SMI for the conversion tool.

How can i include the necessary dependencies for the mibdump command?

Additional info: 
- my MIB is not in the snmplabs.com/asn1 database 
- I use python 2.7 on Ubuntu
- I am obviously new to MIBs and Python, which might not be a good constellation here

Comment: http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/mibdump.html#specifying-mib-source

Comment: Are they not in `/usr/share/snmp`? You can put them there. Installing Net-SNMP will do that...

Comment: https://l3net.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/installing-net-snmp-mibs-on-ubuntu-and-debian/

Comment: Thanks, it seems I did not have SNMPv2-SMI "enabled" because I did not edit the snmp.conf according to your source!